# Inhomogeneous polynomial and points at infinity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $f=X^2-Y$ be a polynomial in $k[X,Y]$, so $V(Z)$ is a parabola:

$V(f)$:

[image]

According to Bézout theorem the $y$-axis has to intersect the parabola two times.

We know the y-axis meets the parabola in $P$.

In order to find the point in the infinite of the intersection, let's the homogenization of $f$ be $F=X^2-YZ$.

In order to find the points in the infinity we only have to find these points:

$$V(F)\cap V(Z)=P_1=\{(0:1:0)\}$$

If we deshomogenize F in $Z$ we get  back $f=X^2-Y$, the points in the finite.

Now, if we deshomogenize F in $Y$ and $X$ we get $f_1=X^2-Z$ and $f_2=1-YZ$.

$V(f_1)$:

[image]

$V(f_2)$:

[image]

My question is what's the meaning of $f_1$ and $f_2$? I'm trying to understand intuitively the meaning of homogenization/deshomogenization of a polynomial and their relation with the points at infinity.

I'm sorry if my question is a little vague, but I'm really confused with these concepts.

I really need help

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**

My doubt can be summarize in these questions:

What happens if we deshomogenize the polynomial in another variable? (other than $z$)

Is this procedure useful to understand the behavior of the curve at a given point? (in our case point $P$)

Comment: why downvoted??

Comment: Indeed, why downvote this question? It is quite legitimate for a beginner to wonder at the interplay between affine and projective geometry.

Comment: The $y$-axis is $V(X)$, why do you use $V(Z)$ for the intersection? By coincidence it makes no difference here.

Answer (score 0):

$V_{\mathbb{P}^2}(X^2-YZ)$ is a [conical surface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_surface). See the link for a nice picture of the preimage in $\mathbb{A}^3$. When you dehomogenize with respect to $X$, you cut this surface with the plane $X=1$ and obtain a [conic section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic), namely the hyperbola. The intersection with the planes $Y=1$ and $Z=1$ gives parabola.

Comment: Yes, I know that. My problem is how I can understand the behavior of this surface at a given point in terms of infinite/finite points when we dehomogenize in respect to other variable than $Z$. Did you follow me? thank you for your answer.